# Facebook Unity3d sdk: no notification after send invite request to friends

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

This question should be how to:

I send the :

```
FB.AppRequest(
            "Come to play the game",
            null,
            FriendSelectorFiltersArr,
            excludeIds,
            null,
            FriendSelectorData,
            "Good game",
            InvitFriendCallBack
        );
```

from my app.

From the mobile device, I got notification from Facebook app. But the message is not show, it just says:

> xxx invited you to play xxx game

If I login through web browser from PC, There is no notification, I only can check out the invite message from **Home -> Games -> Activity -> Invites**. The good thing is I got the full message from there.

question:

What is the different between Invites and Requests??

How can I let the Facebook App to display the full message in the notification?

How can I let the invite display in the notification if player login Facebook through web browser?